# Can i use a "template.html" with TCPDF

Tags: php, templates, tcpdf

I have found an example online using DomPDF and a template.html file on an invoice that is verry handy.

is there a way to do the same with TCPDF?
I have a form that generates a table with dynamic content and then by pressing a button if prints it on to a pdf but in a rudementery style.
By using a template thing would come out nicer.

Can it be done ?

thank you all

Comment: TCPDF is a library to create documents, not to convert an html layout to PDF. If that is what you want, then why do you want to use TCPDF at all? Why not use a HTML to PDF converter?

Comment: hello and thank you for the reply but that is my problem... i am shooting in the dark.... so i need to find a way to convert php into html and then try to output it to to pdf ?

Comment: What speaks against using DOMpdf as in the example you found? That probably is familiar for you, outputting html by means of php. And then you convert tht to a PDF document using that library. Works. If you need more precise control over the output, so pixel based instead of a rough page layout, then you should use something like tcpdf or libPDF and forget about html to describe the layout.

Comment: thank you for the help but i decided to stick to the easy option, tcpdf. simple and it works..... but thank you all for the input